# Why are there barcode readers on the bridge of the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, technology, star-trek-into-darkness

Devices on the bridge:

[image: devices on the bridge]

Now, compare them with barcode readers:

[image: barcode reader][image]

They certainly look like barcode readers. What sort of devices are they (in-universe)? Any info on what the props are (out-of-universe)?

Comment: Lens flare generators.

Comment: They’re for reading barcodes.

Comment: Reminds me of the 60's series Raumpatrouille, where they had to resort to many common household items to put together a space ship bridge :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raumpatrouille_%E2%80%93_Die_phantastischen_Abenteuer_des_Raumschiffes_Orion#Special_effects_and_set_decoration

Comment: counter question, why are there hand phasers in my local tesco?

Comment: @Boldewyn -  Was that the one with the talking rat who wants to be a chef?

Comment: @Valorum no talking rats, but the aliens where called "Frogs". (The german-speaking crew of the Orion having called them "Frösche", then deciding that sounded too normal, so starting to use the English translation: Frog)

Comment: Reading Barcodes in order to get their Trilitium at the best pricing.

Comment: At my local supermarket the newbie point-of-sale staff are made to wear red sweaters on their first month on the job.

Comment: I see the _Star Trek_ tradition of using [odd-looking off-the-shelf items as futuristic gadget props](http://spinoff.comicbookresources.com/2013/05/15/tv-legends-revealed-were-mccoys-star-trek-instruments-salt-shakers/) is still alive!

Comment: @Valorum: Only now I realize you are alluding to the slight superficial similarity between the words ["Ratatouille"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratatouille) and "Raumpatrouille" (the latter being the German word for "space patrol").

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - It only took you three months? Damn. I need to make my puns more obscure.

Answer (score 50):

### Out of Universe

Yep. Those are indeed barcode scanners. They were apparently purchased by Paramount Pictures from a company called [BarcodesInc](https://www.barcodesinc.com/news/?tag=star-trek).

---

[image]

**Image courtesy of www.Barcodesinc.com**

Comment: While I've upvoted this (for frankly the awesome image find) I don't think it really answers the question... "Why did they use barcode scanners?"

Comment: @Liath They are not barcode scanners - they are futuristic devices that happen to look like barcode scanners, and it's cheaper and easier to buy a bunch of barcode scanners than to specially order things that look like them.

Comment: So, if not barcode scanners, what is their in-universe purpose?

Comment: @Liath - The question also asks for their out-of-universe provenance.

Comment: While interesting and factual, this does not answer the question of **why** they are there.

Comment: @Trisped - If I may quote directly from [the question asked](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/135932/20774); "***Any info on what the props are (out-of-universe)?***".

Comment: @Trisped - That being said, I do accept fully that you are right in the there's no in-universe explanation offered in my answer, which is why I've labeled it accordingly.

Comment: @Valorum the actual question is "_Why are there barcode readers on the bridge of the Enterprise?_".  The other two are bonus questions, only one of which is addressed by this answer.

Comment: @trisped - I would encourage you to write your own answer adressing the in-universe explanation, should one exist.

Comment: @Valorum I guess I was less clear then intended.  I feel your answer does not answer the question asked and should be updated, even if the update only adds, "There is no information on what the scanners are for."

Comment: @Trisped - My answer is 100% clear that it's about the out-of-universe portion of the question. If I find any in-universe info about what these things are, I'll add it as a new section.

Comment: I don't know if there's any better answer to "What in-universe purpose do they serve?" than "They look sciencey."

Comment: @Emrakul - I've reached out to the Director, the art designer and the props guys. Hopefully one of those can give us a suitably trekkie answer. Frustratingly the Director did an online Q&A session a couple of days ago which I missed. Shame really.

Answer (score 17):

Valorum's answer explains what they are, but not the why.

Why are they used?

Because they're a cheap way to get a fairly high-tech looking prop that 99.99% of people will not realise are barcode scanners. It's far cheaper and faster to buy a bunch of $50 barcode scanners, than it is to build an equivalent number of light up props.

Barcode scanners suit a spaceship because they're interesting, unusual shapes that give off light and can look complicated and scientific.

In short, they make The Enterprise look spaceship-y very cheaply, using simple props that most people won't take a second glance at.

Answer (score 5):

Their general appearance seems to be consistent with how phasers look in several of the later of the original Star Trek eras:

[image]

It is possible that these are just one of the reboot interpretations of the phasers found in earlier series.

They also appear somewhat consistent with other handheld scanner devices from the earlier series.

Note that there is no current in-universe explanation as to what these devices are used for, so for the moment, all that can really be done is speculation as to the purpose of the devices. Given their appearance of fitting well in a hand and having a forward-facing light element or photoreceptor, it's possible these are phasers or scanners.

Comment: I have some doubts that phasers would be propped up on elevated positions all over the bridge, and sometimes even two on a single workplace.

Comment: If any hostiles reach the bridge, they and everyone else will have access to phasers. In most cases, that should mean a home team victory, because the crew will generally be both more numerous and closer to the phasers. I think the captain's station is the only one that obviously has two, which might make sense.

Comment: Phasers in 'Beyond' and all other parts of the reboot have more of an actual pistol-shape instead of barcodescanner- or TV-remote-shape.

Comment: @steenbergh Are you saying there is only one shape any device can have? Going by the iterations, these might be newer or older models of phasers that haven't quite been phased out yet (pun not intended).

Comment: @Nzall There are no phasers of this description depicted on-screen in the reboot series (2009, Darkness and Beyond), so I do't think there's reason to assume the barcode scanners represent phasers on the bridge.

Comment: @steenbergh That's why I said it's also possible these are scanners. And they may even be emergency lighting. As long as we don't have confirmation of the creators what these are, we can't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have some in-universe fun of trying to explain them... In present day bar codes are being used to do things other than for sales. They're used for transmitting data for a whole bunch of things and for interacting in an AR environment. So, even though we have no proof of such things, it is possible that they are there for that purpose, so that if some AR thing comes onto the bridge you would want most of your crew to be able to get to a reader and use it.

Never seen it and hypothetically the entire bridge should have cameras filming the area already. Maybe they're just cameras?