# Star Trek Beyond, NCC 1701-A Destroyed, why was rebuilt ship not named -B?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

In Star Trek Beyond they destroy the Enterprise NCC-1701-A. As such, why is the new ship being built also called the NCC-1701-A instead of -B, as in the original movies?

Comment: As far as I know, the designations change when the class changes or has a major overhaul. Also, welcome to SFF! In the future you'll want to include spoiler boxes to reduce any issues with people who haven't seen the movie!

Comment: @Timpanus - They trash it about ten minutes into the film. Also it was shown [in the trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRVD32rnzOw) and even on the billboard advert. It's hardly a spoiler unless you've been living in a cave.

Comment: _"In Star Trek Beyond they destroy the Enterprise NCC-1701-A"_ No, they don't.

Comment: @Valorum: I'd like to see stats on how many SFF users live in a cave. Probably quite a few :) Point stands, this is a major plot point, and "it was in the trailer and the trailer spoilt it too" is not an excuse. I avoid trailers for this reason! Common courtesy not to give away major plot points in the network sidebars. This question can easily be made not to give away a major plot point to those who have not seen the movie. "Why haven't you seen it already?" is also not a valid counter-argument.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I disagree. The destruction of the Enterprise is neither surprising, nor plot-significant beyond explaining why they're not on the Enterprise for much of the film.

Comment: @Valorum point taken, but still a good habit to introduce early! :)

Comment: @Valorum: Pretty surprising if you didn't know it was going to happen

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - My personal opinion is that a spoiler is something that's *intended to surprise*. Simple plot points aren't spoilers.

Comment: @Valorum: Hard to dispute that objectively. Subjectively, I really wish I didn't know ahead of time that the Ent was going to be ripped to shreds, because that surprise would have been mint :) It's a fairly significant "character death", after all!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - My local cinema had a poster outside (similar to [this one](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-KEpFGsMRK7E/V5uZO7ZfytI/AAAAAAAACgM/OW2x7x5XUXUAZsFTYLjePNxW5E1nf6lFgCLcB/s640/star_trek_beyond_ver16_xlg-1.jpg)) that showed the crew looking up at the wrecked Enterprise. It ain't a spoiler if it's on the poster :-)

Comment: @Valorum: That's your cinema! Mine didn't have that :)

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, your original assumption is incorrect.

The ship that was destroyed was NCC-1701 not NCC-1701-A

[image]

[image]

So, when the **new** ship is constructed at the end of ST:B IT was designated NCC-1701-A.

Comment: And here I thought the Enterprise NCC-1701 had been destroyed the moment I saw it for the first time in Star Trek (2011) ...

Comment: Ahem - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VufmQ.png

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : 2011?

Comment: Presumably he means 2009 and his reaction to the design...not an actual ship destroyed.

Comment: @Praxis: Sorry, I meant 2009 indeed. One of those recent years. (As I don't want to pay for Abramsverse movies, I waited until they were on some kind of free TV, so 2011 may indeed have been the year when the 2009 film became available for me ;) ) Other than that, to remove any doubt, Paulie's interpretation is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : Fair enough.  I was thinking, though, that you might be referring to *Into Darkness* (2013), where the Enterprise NCC-1701 is very, very badly damaged by the end of the film (unlike in 2009), and the ship then undergoes a major repair / refit, whose result is seen in the closing imagery.

Comment: @Praxis: Ah, no. I was indeed making a very subjective, rather snide remark based upon my personal opinion on the redesigned Enterprise. And given the confusing I am creating here, let me close this by stating that my opinion of calling the 11th film in the franchise simply "Star Trek", without any official subtitle, is equally low.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper : Well, we certainly agree on all of those points.  I don't like the new franchise (although *Beyond* was a little better than I thought it would be, given that my expectations were essentially zero), I hate the excessive action emphasis, I hate the convoluted nonsensical plots, and I think the ship looks like a brewery with giant blowdryers.

Comment: @praxis - Don't forget [all the barcode readers on the ship's bridge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135932/why-are-there-barcode-readers-on-the-bridge-of-the-enterprise)

Comment: @Valorum : Wouldn't want to be stranded in the Beta Quadrant without one....

Comment: @praxis, I'm guessing you know the interior sets actually were a Budweiser plant?

Answer (score -5):

At least originally, the full letter jump has always accompanied a complete change in the class of starship.

Comment: NCC-1701 was a Constitution class ship. NCC-1701-A was a Constitution class ship. Controversial due to the far-reaching nature of the refit, but it was the same class.

Comment: Untrue, both the original NCC-1701 and NCC-1701-A were Constitution class.

Comment: Point is, you would not give a different ship an identical registry. That's literally contrary to the purpose of a registry. Class has basically nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Polygnome right. In the original timeline, here are the Enterprises and their classes: 1701 (no letter) - Constitution, 1701-A - Constitution, 1701-B - Excelsior, 1701-C - Ambassador, 1701-D - Galaxy, 1701-E - Sovereign. The no-letter original as well as C and D were destroyed in battle. A was decommissioned (final fate unknown, but likely scrapped), and the fates of B and E unclear.

Comment: @RobertColumbia  E is still intact in Nemesis (damaged, but its towed to a dock), so its safe to assume it still exist. Maybe at one time writers decide to make additional main-timeline events after nemesis that further explain what happens to it, but for now i'd say its still intact.